# Conservation of energy in the D'Alembert solution to the wave equation in a semi-infinite domain

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, energy-conservation

Given that the most general solution to the wave equation 
$$ c^2\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}  = \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}$$ can be given as

$$ y = f(x+ct) + g(x-ct),$$ I'm trying to show that the expression for the energy 
$$  E = \int_{0}^{\infty} \! dx\left(\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})^{2} + \frac{1}{2}c^2(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})^2\right)$$ is invariant in time specifically in the domain $0 \leq x < \infty, $ when $y(0, t) = 0,  \forall t > 0$ and when $y \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

I've tried differentiating with respect to time , but this does not eliminate $f$ as if we set $y = f(x+ct)$,

$$ \frac{\partial E}{\partial t} = \int_{0}^{\infty} c^{3}2f'f'' dx.$$ It does seem to eliminate $g$, however.

Is there something about the restricted domain or the boundary conditions which lend a restriction on $f$? Would one need to use method of images to find a restricted form for $f$, one that would yield $\dot{E} = 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the solution, try using the wave equation itself to simplify $\dot{E}$: begin with your unsimplified expression for $E$ and then take its time derivative directly. You should then arrive at:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d} t} = c^2\,\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial\,x}\left( \frac{\partial\,y}{\partial\,x}\,\frac{\partial\,y}{\partial\,t}\right)\,\mathrm{d} x$$

whence you should make some headway.